# Squeeze items with itemize

Tags: lists, itemize, multicol

I feel that I can save some lines in the following list, but I do not know how.

[image]

The split made at `broadband networks` is something I would like to avoid for example.

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true ,urlcolor=blue,urlbordercolor={0 1 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\topmargin=0in
\topskip=0in
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\Myoops}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\name{\LARGE Georgios Samaras}
%MUST leave a blank line after this

\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Conferences Events} All the conferences/events where held in Athens
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Broadband networks.
  \item Internet security.
  \item \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-generation_network}{NGN}s
  \item E-Learning and Webinars.
  \item E-Business.
  \item Windows Phone (Microsoft).
  \item Java, C$^\sharp$ and F$^\sharp$.
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}


\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

However, the document needs `res.cls`, which you can view [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/cv-in-latex/).

By the way, if someone has any other idea of how to save space there, please let me know, since every line that a save helps a lot.

---

If I use 4 in mutlicols, I get:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use `\sc` and related commands. Either `\schape` or `\textsc{...}` then

Comment: It was already there @ChristianHupfer, when I found this template for constructing my CV in the internet.

Comment: That's why one should not use templates. 99.99% of them are rubbish

Comment: But would you suggest me to build my CV @ChristianHupfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among few options you have, one is to use `nosep` as the option to `itemize` (a feature of `enumitem` package). Add `\raggedright` additionally so that the weird justification doesn't spoil the looks.

If adventurous, you may also consider using `tasks` package, which, is good in handling the multicolumn lists. I have added `tasks` environment with all possible options so that you may change the dimensions as per your needs. For details, refer to `tasks` manual.

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true ,urlcolor=blue,urlbordercolor={0 1 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\topmargin=0in
\topskip=0in
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\Myoops}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[more]{tasks}


\begin{document}
\name{\LARGE Georgios Samaras}
%MUST leave a blank line after this

\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Conferences Events} All the conferences/events where held in Athens
\begin{multicols}{4}
\raggedright
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Broadband networks.
  \item Internet security.
  \item \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-generation_network}{NGN}s
  \item E-Learning and Webinars.
  \item E-Business.
  \item Windows Phone (Microsoft).
  \item Java, C$^\sharp$ and F$^\sharp$.
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

With \verb|tasks|:
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize,label=\labelitemi,before-skip=0pt,
                after-skip=-2pt,after-item-skip=0pt,
                column-sep=1em,label-width=0.6em,label-offset=0.1em,
                item-indent=0.2em,label-align=left](3)
  \task Broadband networks.
  \task Internet security.
  \task \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-generation_network}{NGN}s
  \task E-Learning and Webinars.
  \task E-Business.
  \task Windows Phone (Microsoft).
  \task Java, C$^\sharp$ and F$^\sharp$.
\end{tasks}


\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, it is better to use `geometry` package to alter the page layout instead of manual adjustments.

Also, try to avoid two letter commands (`\sc`) for font shapes in favour of `\scshape`. BTW, modifying section titles is better done with either `sectsty` of `titlesec` packages. If you do it manually like in this/your code, you may run in to the risk of losing consistency. Change formatting in the preamble using these packages. (I didn't do it here).

Comment: Thanks. Check my edit, which gives almost the same result. I am getting a compilation error with your code: `! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"!! The key 'tasks/list/column-sep' is unknown and is being ignored.!! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \end{tasks}`

Comment: @gsamaras: May be you need an update of your tex distribution.

Comment: Harish, I did (http://askubuntu.com/questions/657653/dpkg-error-processing-archive-with-texmaker) and now my texmaker is in v. 4.4.1 (the latest available according to its help), the errors are still there.

Comment: @gsamaras: texmaker is not tex distribution. You need to update texlive.

Comment: How should I do that please?

Comment: @gsamaras Please refer:  [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: It won't work..